# common key dictionary to single dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a input request which consists of multiple dictionaries with similar keys and values as  dictionaries.

Here's the input I have.

```
req = {"main1": 
    {"x": {"a":220},"y": {"b":66}},
    "main2": 
    {"x": {"c":"1000","d":"copper"},
    "y": {"c":"1200","d":"Copper"}}}
```

Output I need:

```
{'cable1': {'a': 220, 'c': '1000', 'd': 'copper'}, 'cable2': {'b': 66, 'c': '1200', 'd': 'Copper'}}
```

Here's the try i made:

```
actual_req = []
for attr1, attr2 in req.items():
    for j, k in attr2.items():
        actual_req.append(k)
actual_req[0].update(actual_req[2])
actual_req[1].update(actual_req[3])
data = {'cable1': actual_req[0], 'cable2': actual_req[1]}

print(data)
```

I just need the more generic way of writing in short. It should also handle input with

```
req = {"main1": 
    {"x": {"a":220},"y": {"b":66}},
    "main2": 
    {"x": {"c":"1000","d":"cooper"},
    "y": {"c":"1200","d":"Copper"}},
     "main3": 
    {"x": {"e":20},"y": {"f":6}}}
```

Comment: Why is `output["cable2"]["c"] == "1200"` and not `"1000"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update final dictionary as you go through values of original dictionary:

```
req = {"main1": 
    {"x": {"a":220},"y": {"b":66}},
    "main2": 
    {"x": {"c":"1000","d":"copper"},
    "y": {"c":"1200","d":"Copper"}}}

final_dict = {'cable1': {}, 'cable2': {}}
for v in req.values():
    final_dict['cable1'].update(v['x'])
    final_dict['cable2'].update(v['y'])
```

Final dict would look like this:

```
{'cable1': {'a': 220, 'c': '1000', 'd': 'copper'}, 'cable2': {'b': 66, 'c': '1200', 'd': 'Copper'}}
```